# Assisted Injection with Hilt in Jetpack Compose multi module app

Tags: dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation, assisted-inject

I am having some trouble with assisted Injection in Hilt and Jetpack Compose.
I have set stuff up like here https://medium.com/scalereal/providing-assistedinject-supported-viewmodel-for-composable-using-hilt-ae973632e29a

Just for the sake of it... Code look like this:

ViewModel Implementation. The ViewModel is in the "feature" module:

```
class NoteDetailViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val noteId: String,
    private val notyTaskManager: NotyTaskManager,
    private val noteRepository: NotyNoteRepository
) : ViewModel() {
  
    // Other ViewModel's implementation...
  
    @AssistedFactory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(noteId: String): NoteDetailViewModel
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    companion object {
        fun provideFactory(
            assistedFactory: Factory,
            noteId: String
        ): ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return assistedFactory.create(noteId) as T
            }
        }
    }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
interface AssistedInjectModule
```

Then, in the `MainActivity`, which is the only Activity in the app anyway (app module):

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
    interface ViewModelFactoryProvider {
        fun noteDetailViewModelFactory(): NoteDetailViewModel.Factory
    }
    ...
```

And lastly, the `@Composable` looks like this (located in the feature module):

```
@Composable
fun noteDetailViewModel(noteId: String): NoteDetailViewModel {
    val factory = EntryPointAccessors.fromActivity(
        LocalContext.current as Activity,
        MainActivity.ViewModelFactoryProvider::class.java
    ).noteDetailViewModelFactory()

    return viewModel(factory = NoteDetailViewModel.provideFactory(factory, noteId))
}
```

Can anybody help? Thanks!

There's a couple of problems:
Firstly, the `MainActivity.ViewModelFactoryProvider::class.java` is not accessible in the feature module. Obviously you can't create a circular reference. That's why I tried replacing it with `NoteDetailViewModel.Factory`; it should be the same, right? Unfortunately I get an error saying "cannot cast from Singleton_C to NoteDetailViewModel".

Putting the Composable function in the MainActivity file might also be a solution, but that doesn't work either, obviously...

I solved it another way in the end, using an Annotation class. It works, but I'd like to use the assisted injection.